# Saber el último reinicio de un proceso

Tags: linux, bash, script

Quiero crear un script en shell de linux que me diga si un proceso se ha reiniciado y que me devuelva 1 en caso de OK y 0 en caso de que se haya reiniciado. 
Tengo más o menos estructurado todo, pero me sigue sin funcionar. Estoy intentándolo comparando con la fecha en un fichero.

```
> #!/bin/sh 
>FICHERO=$(cat /tmp/tiempo_proceso.txt)
>PDI=$(pidof ntpd)
>TIME=$(ps -p $PDI -o lstart=)
>if [ $TIME -lt $FICHERO ] then  
> echo"OK"  
>$TIME > /tmp/tiempo_proceso.txt 
>exit 1
>else  
>echo "ntpd was restarted"
>$TIME > /tmp/tiempo_proceso.txt 
>exit 0
>fi
```

A ver si me podéis ayudar. Gracias.